# Adaptive Parallel Payments - Platform Owner Fee

Tags: parallel-processing, paypal-adaptive-payments

We are implementing  parallel payment in our market place website. We are calcualting the commision for the platform owner and sending the same to the paypal of the owner and the other payments to the respective sellers. In this, the paypal fee is deducted for the commission amount received by the market owner. Will this fee be deducted by mandatory by paypal or is there a way that we can setup that no fees is deducted for the platform owner

Comment: Hey - have you been able to reslove this? Im looking for informations about the same thing ritght now: how to setup platform fee. I see two possible ways of doing that: one extra parrarel payment or by payment settings if thats possible.